# Instrumenting child class when transformation depends on the instrumented parent type, from the same Plugin

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm new to bytebuddy, and I am writing a `Plugin` for maven to perform some offline type enhancements.
I transform annotated types, which can themselves have an annotated parent/super type.

I'm having issues with transformations that depend on the enhanced supertype, e.g. adding a default constructor.

```
 builder = builder.defineConstructor(Visibility.PACKAGE_PRIVATE)
                  .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE);
```

which gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call super (or default) method for`, because as I understand, only the enhanced version of the parent class defines a default constructor in this case.

If any, what would be the right way of making the maven-bytebuddy-plugin prefer the enhanced version when resolving super types ?

I've written a test class for the plugin where I could easily toy with a `ByteBuddy` instance configuration, but could not find any way to make it work. I've tried messing with `ClassFileLocator`, `TypePool`, or registering an `AuxiliaryType` in the type builder but the redefinition of the child class keeps failing on `make()`.
Although the parent type was already enhanced and loaded, I'm out of ideas and can't get the builder to resolve it instead of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to disable these checks when creating a class. You are in a way relying on a future instrumentation, this was not considered in Byte Buddy's original design and is hard to overcome.

What you can do instead, would be to implement your own `Implementation` where you do not include these checks. Have a look at the implementation of `SuperMethodCall`, in a way, copy the code of it (it's not much) and remove the consistency checks. That's the only way I would know how to do it as things are now.

Comment: Alright, I guess I could do that indeed - so far I only need this for the default constructor.

Since then, I tried harder and had success for my test class for the plugin by using a `ClassFileLocator.Compound` of a .Simple and .ofSystemLoader().
Then, creating a TypePool for that classFileLocator and simply reseting the typePool's cache every time I instrument a type and regenerate the ClassFileLocator.Simple with the new set of instrumented types.
I looks a bit far fetched to me, but works.

Comment: Do you think I could in some way extend the plugin processor in the maven-bytebuddy-plugin mojo to do the same ?
It would greatly simplify my transformer if I could just assume the parent type was always instrumented already, instead of walking up the class hierarchy and redoing the same computations over parents' fields to generate some other static fields in the child class.

Comment: You could certainly adjust it to provide types from a custom type pool. Currently, there is however no guarantee over the order of transformations.